# Are thses two notations &switch->port->data and &(switch->port->data) same in C?

Tags: c, pointers, structure, dereference

I thought it as switch is the main structure, port is the nested structure and data is a value in port structure. And by this notation we are taking address of the "data" value.

Comment: Have you try some tests ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they are the same because [`->` takes precedence over `&`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).